# Как ограничить доступ - показывать или не показывать блок?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Как можно ограничить доступ к пункту меню.

Есть таблица с доступами, ее структура:

```
id
id_staff
id_cabinet (id кабинета в который может заходить сотрудник)
vid_access (вид доступа, например: access_balance
access (если 0 то запрещен доступ, если 1 то разрешен)
```

Как, допустим, ограничить доступ к разделу меню с названием `balance`?

Что посоветуете?

Comment: Получить значение access/vid\_access, проверить на наличие нужных данных, показать пункт, если они присутствуют. Тут могут быть варианты?

Comment: это и коню понятно. 

у меня на странице, есть несколько пунктов которые надо ограничить в доступе. 

как достать значение из поля access для пункта balance, который соответствует виду доступа access_balance

думал сделать что-то типо 

if ($row['vid_access'] == 'access_balance' ) { if ($row['access'] == '1' ) { echo 'доступ разрешен'; } }


но что-то не очень то хочет работать, да и длинный вариант не по феншую как-то, реально ли коротким решением сделать?